# Join XML strings pulled from the web using python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to join two xml files I'm pulling from the web. I just need the second XML file to be added at the end of the first. To this this I've tried to pull the XML from the web, convert them to strings, join them then create a new tree from the conjoined string.

```
urls = 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/guestbook.asp', 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/guestbook.asp'


for url in urls:
    url = url[0]
    XML = requests.get(url)

    XML_str = XML.content + XML_str


XML_data =  ET.fromstring(XML_str)
tree = ET.ElementTree(XML_data)
```

However when I do this I get the following error.

Error: lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document, line 1, column 326

The XML string looks fine to me and I think the error is realted to there being two declaratoin lines form each feed (e.g. )

does anyone know a better way to join two XML files being pulled from the web without writing to disk....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just concatenate two xml files since there will be two xml declarations and two root elements.

Instead, you should use [ElementTree.append()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append). Here's an example where the guests from the second guestbook xml are appended to the guestbook of the first xml:

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

urls = 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/guestbook.asp', 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/guestbook.asp'
xml_list = [requests.get(url).content for url in urls]

root1 = ET.fromstring(xml_list[0])
root2 = ET.fromstring(xml_list[1])

for element in root2.findall('guest'):
    root1.append(element)

print ET.tostring(root1)
```

prints (I've indented it for readability):

```
<guestbook>
    <guest>
        <fname>Terje</fname>
        <lname>Beck</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>Jan</fname>
        <lname>Refsnes</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>Torleif</fname>
        <lname>Rasmussen</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>anton</fname>
        <lname>chek</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>stale</fname>
        <lname>refsnes</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>hari</fname>
        <lname>prawin</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>Hege</fname>
        <lname>Refsnes</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>Terje</fname>
        <lname>Beck</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>Jan</fname>
        <lname>Refsnes</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>Torleif</fname>
        <lname>Rasmussen</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>anton</fname>
        <lname>chek</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>stale</fname>
        <lname>refsnes</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>hari</fname>
        <lname>prawin</lname>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <fname>Hege</fname>
        <lname>Refsnes</lname>
    </guest>
</guestbook>
```

Answer (score 1):

Every tree has a single root node. So each of your `XML_str`s must be appended to some common root node. Here is how you could do that:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import requests
urls = 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/guestbook.asp', 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/guestbook.asp'

root = ET.Element('root')
for url in urls:
    XML = requests.get(url)
    root.append(ET.fromstring(XML.content))
tree = root.getroottree()    
print(ET.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```